# One-way anova data normality assumption

Tags: anova, normal-distribution, spss, normality-assumption

The one-way anova assumptions are:

1. independent and identically distributed variables (or, less precisely, “independent observations”);
2. independent and identically distributed variables (or, less precisely, “independent observations”);
   homoscedasticity: the dependent variable has the same variance within each population;
3. normality: the dependent variable is normally distributed within each population;

source: https://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-one-way-anova/

I  have a dataset pictured below

[image: dataset]

If I'm trying to do a one way anova on the eyes score data, it should fail because the data is not normally distributed right?  SPSS can do a one way anova but it gives no value for the F-statistic or significance / p-value.

Comment: Is "Eyes" your dependent variable? If so, everyone in control got a 4, everyone in .1 micro got a 3, and everyone in 1 micro got a 2? If so, there is no variability within groups. Within-group variability goes in the denominator of the F-statistic, so it will equal infinity. You cannot run a statistical test on the data as you have presented it.

Comment: Yes eyes is the dependent var.  Is it not possible to run a simple t test on the data either? (Disregarding the effects of multiple t test comparisons)

Comment: No, a t-test is mathematically the same as an ANOVA with two groups. You cannot do hypothesis testing with that data as it is. Group perfectly explains the dep. variable. You don't need statistics to analyze this data because there is no randomness in it. It's likely that your measurement instrument is too coarse to find real differences between units.